# Amazon S3 modify bucket policy using boto/boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am looking for modifying S3 bucket policy using boto/boto3. I have found two modes in boto3 through which we can perform operation on bucket policy.

```
# i can get bucket policy object as follows
import boto3
s3_conn = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_policy = s3_conn.BucketPolicy('bucket_name')
# i can make put(), load(), policy on bucket_policy object.

#similar in other way i can use following code
policy = s3_conn.get_bucket_policy(Bucket='bucket_name')
# similar to this there are two other calls put_bucket_policy and delete_bucket_policy.
```

I am looking for update bucket policy in which i can add more attributes.

eg. I want to add one more entry under Statement key of following policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy14564645656",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Stmt1445654645618",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::6164563645030:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:Get*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/abc/*"
    }]
}
```

Is there any straight forward way to do this. One very weird way is to add entry in JSON then PUT this as new policy but i am looking for call which allows user to update the policy without knowing exiting policy.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar requirement of having to modify bucket and KMS policies programmatically. I came up with my own class which treat policies and statements as object. It's wrapped up in a pip package 'awspolicy' - https://github.com/totoleon/AwsPolicy

I hope it can help. Quick example:

```
import boto3
from awspolicy import BucketPolicy

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'hailong-python'

# Load the bucket policy as an object
bucket_policy = BucketPolicy(serviceModule=s3_client, resourceIdentifer=bucket_name)

# Select the statement that will be modified
statement_to_modify = bucket_policy.select_statement('AutomatedRestrictiveAccess')

# Insert new_user_arn into the list of Principal['AWS']
new_user_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::888888888888:user/daniel'
statement_to_modify.Principal['AWS'].append(new_user_arn)

# Save change of the statement
statement_to_modify.save()

# Save change of the policy. This will update the bucket policy
statement_to_modify.source_policy.save() # Or bucket_policy.save()
```

Answer (score 5):

Current boto3 API doesn't have a function to APPEND the bucket policy, whether add another items/elements/attributes.  You need load and manipulate the JSON yourself. E.g. write script load the policy into a dict, append the "Statement"  element list,  then use the policy.put to replace the whole policy. Without the original statement id, user policy will be appended. HOWEVER, there is no way to tell whether later user policy will override rules of the earlier one.

For example

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_policy = s3_resource.BucketPolicy('bucket_name')

# Or use client to get Bucket policy
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
policy = s3_client.get_bucket_policy(Bucket='bucket_name')

# assign policy using s3 resource 
user_policy = { "Effect": "Allow",... } 
new_policy =  policy['Statement'].append(user_policy)
bucket_policy.put(Policy=new_policy)
```

The user don't need know the old policy in the process.

Comment: You need a Client() to call get_bucket_policy.

Answer (score 2):

IAM does not provide a way to update a policy without providing a whole, valid policy as a replacement. You need to perform a PUT, passing in the original policy name.